# Index conflicts when restoring to an active MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Periodically when we do a `mongorestore` we're getting index constraint errors. Initially, it seemed entirely impossible that you can get an index error when restoring a DB but it appears the root cause is that `mongorestore` yields during the operation. This allows an item on a key to be inserted by the restore **and** by a user, therefore when the index is applied at the end, it errors.

Here's an example, lets imagine we have a collection `foo` with a unique index on "title".

```
mongorestore --host myDb --db foo --drop auth
// foo is dropped
// RESTORE: foo.insert({ title : "A" });
// RESTORE: foo.insert({ title : "B" });
// restore yields to insert
// USER: foo.insert({ title : "C" });
// user yields back to restore
// RESTORE: foo.insert({ title : "C" });
// RESTORE: foo.ensureIndex({ title : 1 }, { unique : true }) -- ERROR E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.data.$title_1
```

Is there anyway to prevent this during a `mongorestore`? It seems I need a method to temporarily write lock an entire database during `mongorestore`. The only thing I could find was `db.fsyncLock` but that locks the entire `mongod` and not just the database I'm working on.